# Sherlock and Anagrams Optimization

Tags: c++, algorithm, strings

From Hackerrank:

> Given a string S, find the number of "unordered anagrammatic pairs" of substrings. In other words, find the number of unordered pairs of substrings of  S that are anagrams of each other.
>
> Two strings are **anagrams** of each other if the letters of one string can be rearranged to form the other string.
>
> **Input Format**
>
> First line contains T, the number of testcases. Each testcase consists of string  S in one line.
>
> **Constraints**
>
> 1 <= t <= 10
>
> 2 <= length(s) <= 100
>
> String S contains only the lowercase letters of the English alphabet.
>
> **Output Format**
>
> For each testcase, print the required answer in one line.

I am losing two test cases with Time Limit Exceeded. Can somebody please tell me how to optimize the code?

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>

using namespace std;

int sherlockAndAnagrams(string s)
{ 

    unordered_map<char,int> count1,count2;
    unordered_map<char,int>::iterator it;
    int l=s.length();
    int len1,len2;
    int wall1,wall2;
    int cnt=0;
    int flg=0;
    int i,j;
    int dflg;
    wall1=0,wall2=l-1;
    for(wall1=0;wall1<l-1;++wall1)
    {
        len1=1;
        count1.clear();
        for(i=wall1;i<l-1;++i,++len1)
        {
            ++count1[s[i]];
            for(wall2=l-1;wall2>wall1;--wall2)
            {
                len2=1;
                count2.clear();
                flg=0;
                dflg=0;
                for(j=wall2;j>wall1;--j,++len2)
                {
                    ++count2[s[j]];
                    if(len2>len1)
                        break;
                    if(len2==len1)
                    {
                        dflg=1;
                        for(it=count1.begin();it!=count1.end();++it)
                        {
                            if(it->second!=count2[it->first])
                            {
                                flg=1;
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                        break;
                    }
                }
                if(dflg==1 && flg==0)
                        ++cnt;
            }
        }
    }
    return cnt;
}





int main() {
        int q;
        cin >> q;
        for(int a0 = 0; a0 < q; a0++){
            string s;
            cin >> s;
            int result = sherlockAndAnagrams(s);
            cout << result << endl;
        }
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: You are currently brute-forcing the solution. Optimizing this will require you to revisit the fundamental algorithm behind the code.

Comment: Here's a key insight: There are not that many possible substrings in a string of length <= 100.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your problem is not in the code, but in your algorithm. Brute-forcing the solution as you are doing is fundamentally slow, and you need to tackle the problem from a different angle if you want to make a substantial dent in your runtime.

The problem is constrained in two specific ways we can exploit:

1. Only letters in the 'a'->'z' range are admissible. That's only 26 letters.
2. Only strings of length <= 100 characters are admissible. By extension, this means we'll never have more than 100 substrings of a given length to deal with.

Now, if I had a function that converts a substring into "some" representation that's common between annagrammic pairs, but only between annagrammic pairs, I could simply generate that representation for each substring and work off that datastructure instead (probably by using it as a key to a map of number of instances seen).

Since we only have 26 possible letters, a simple `std::array<uint8_t, 26>`, where each cell represents the number of times a given letter appears in the substring, has all the properties we need.

Just to make sure I'm not spouting nonsense, I gave it a try, and my solution using these principles solves all the hackerrank test cases in under 10ms.

I encourage you to give it a try by yourself, but if you request it, I'll be glad to post the code for my solution here.

Comment: Hey Frank, Thanks for the assistance. I have Modified my code which runs at O(26*N3),                                     https://drive.google.com/open?id=0By1znW_9FUFTYV9yRHRBMlMySXM   , Is there is anymore optimization you can tell me please.Maybe O(N2)